# Unknown Function Error with Jedi-Vim plugin on GVim and Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, vim

`:python import jedi` gives me no error and  `:echo has("python")` returns `1`

When loading a python file i get:

```
    Error detected while processing C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\bundle\after\ftplugin
    \python\jedi.vim:
    line    1:
    E117: Unknown function: jedi#init_python
    E15: Invalid expression: !jedi#init_python()
    line    5:
    E121: Undefined variable: g:jedi#auto_initialization
    E15: Invalid expression: g:jedi#auto_initialization
    Error detected while processing C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\bundle\after\syntax\p
    ython.vim:
    line    1:
    E117: Unknown function: jedi#init_python
    E15: Invalid expression: !jedi#init_python()
    line    5:
    E121: Undefined variable: g:jedi#show_call_signatures
    E15: Invalid expression: g:jedi#show_call_signatures > 0 && has('conceal')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The issuetracker is  [this way](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues)

Comment: moved there. thanks :)